# Pop up to only show for the doc owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, popup

I have the following script for a simple pop up on opening the doc. Is there any way for this pop up to only show to the sheet owner and not all the other people the doc is shared with?

```
function onOpen() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var Alert = ui.alert("TEXT HERE");
}
```

My use case for this, is a message visible to only me as the doc owner, which I don't want anybody else with sharing rights, ie clients, to see.

Comment: Have you tried anything that might restrict the code to specific `User`s in the current `Session`? Review the official documentation

Comment: I am really new to apps script and not a coder at all. I do struggle with the nature and structure of it. I found the script elsewhere and am hoping for a bit more help from a guru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to open the dialog only when owner opens the Spreadsheet.
- When the shared users who are not owner open the Spreadsheet, you don't want to open the dialog.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

In this modification, it knows whether owner opened the Spreadsheet by retrieving the email of active user.

- When owner opens the Spreadsheet, the value of `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` is owner's email.
- When users, who are not owner, open the Spreadsheet, no value of `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` is retrieved.

This is used.

#### Modified script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  if (email) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var Alert = ui.alert("TEXT HERE");
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In the case of your script, it is not required to install the function as the installable trigger of OnOpen.
- Even if the installable trigger of OnOpen is installed, when users open the Spreadsheet, no value of `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` is retrieved. So I think that this can be used. At that time, `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` has owner's email.

#### Reference:

- [getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit 1:

If all users install the trigger, `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` returns the value. So the value is required to be compared with that of the registered users. In this sample script, it supposes as follows.

- Users of "email1" and "email2" install the installable trigger of OnOpen by **each user**.

#### Sample script:

```
var users = ["email1", "email2",,,]; // Please set emails of users who can open the dialog.
var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
if (users.indexOf(email) > -1) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var Alert = ui.alert("TEXT HERE");
}
```

### Edit 2:

When I tested this situation by 3 users just now, I noticed new issue.

At first, it supposes as follows.

- Spreadsheet is shared and used by 3 users who are owner, user1 and user2.
- Function is run `onOpen_sample(){}` when the Spreadsheet is opened.
- When owner and user1 can run the script and open a dialog `ui.alert("TEXT HERE")`.

In this situation, the following results are obtained.

1. Owner installed `onOpen_sample()` as a trigger of OnOpen.

   - `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` returns owner's email.
   - `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` returns owner's email.
2. User1 installed `onOpen_sample()` as a trigger of OnOpen.

   - `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` returns no value.
   - `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` returns user1's email.

Here,

1. User2 doesn't install `onOpen_sample()` as a trigger of OnOpen.

   - `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` returns no value.
   - `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` returns user1's email.

     - **This is not owner's email.**

And furthermore,

1. User2 installed `onOpen_sample()` as a trigger of OnOpen.

   - `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` returns no value.
   - `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` returns owner's email.

     - **This is not user2's email.**

And also, when I installed the trigger of OnOpen several times, even if user1 and user2 install the trigger, `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` got to return only owner's email.

By these, all users can run the script and open the dialog. I thought that your issue might be this. I think that this might be a bug. So I would like to report this to the issue tracker.

From this situation, in the current stage, it was found the following result.

1. Only owner can run the script and open the dialog.
2. Specific users cannot run the script and open the dialog.

I apologize that your issue was not resolved. If I found the workaround, I would like to report here.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Yes you understood the question great. Thanks for the added info. One further question is it also possible to also add a specific user, whom the sheet is shared with, to be able to see the dialog along with the owner

Comment: @user10637952 Thank you for replying. About your 1st question, did my modification work? About your 2nd question, you want to open the dialog only when owner and the specific users open the Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, in this case, all the specific users are required to install the trigger of OnOpen. By this, each email can be retrieved by using ``Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()``. At that time, please replace ``getActiveUser()`` to ``getEffectiveUser()`` in my modified script. Also you can compare the each email address. About this, please modify for your situation.

Comment: @user10637952 Is there anything that I can do for your 2 questions? If my both answers were not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. I would like to think of the solutions to resolve your issues.

Comment: the first script changes worked great. When trying to add another user to see the dialog box with the change to Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(). I created an installable trigger and it works, however, the dialog now shows for all users not just the one who created the trigger

Comment: @user10637952 Thank you for replying. In your situation, I added a sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Hi, when I add your sample script, with the added emails of the two users, and try and install the trigger, I am not allowed as there is no function to install it too. I tried adding function onOpen() to the top of your sample script and installing the trigger then but the dialog when then open for all users again. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong as my knowledge of apps script and triggers is minimal

Comment: @user10637952 I cannot understand about ``I am not allowed as there is no function to install it too.``. Can I ask you about it? I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @user10637952 You try to install the trigger of other user by yourself?

Comment: @user10637952 In order to correctly replicate your current situation, can you add your current script to your question?

Comment: when I click "Add Trigger" and the dialog opens under the section "Choose which function to run" there is no option so when I try and save the trigger all I get is a message saying "Something went wrong. Please reload the page to try again". I tried reloading a few times and the same message appears

Comment: I install the script as myself, the owner of the document. Then I share it with another account to check if it works as needed.                                                   
 var users = ["email1", "email2",,,]; // Please set emails of users who can open the dialog.
var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
if (users.indexOf(email) > -1) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var Alert = ui.alert("text");
}

Comment: @user10637952 When you install a trigger of OnOpen, that is for your trigger. When you want to retrieve other user's email, the user is required to install the trigger by the user. I said ``all the specific users are required to install the trigger of OnOpen.`` at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842883/pop-up-to-only-show-for-the-doc-owner/54847341?noredirect=1#comment96467895_54847341). I apologize for my poor English skill. By the way, when you put the script, please add it to your question. Because it is difficult to see the script in the comment.

Comment: I try add the trigger as the owner and this happens. When I click "Add Trigger" and the dialog opens, under the section "Choose which function to run" there is no option to choose a fucntion, so when I try and save the trigger all I get is a message saying "Something went wrong. Please reload the page to try again" The same issue happens if I try and install the trigger as another user

Comment: @user10637952 When I tested this situation by 3 users just now, I noticed new issue. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @user10637952 Thank you for testing it. I think that it might be a bug. And also I think that this bug might have been added recently. I apologize for this situation.