# How to get current user name (mail id) in app script

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get the current user's email address using Google Apps Script?

For example, if my Google Sheet is shared among different users and multiple users are accessing the same sheet concurrently.

I'd like to capture the individual user name for whoever has modified text in Column A and record it in column Z.

I've tried using:

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

However this isn't working, it returns nothing.

Comment: Did you read the security restrictions associated with that method?

Comment: @kalyan4uonly Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54842883/7108653